# Bad errors: platform does not support this image failed to read header: unsupported

Tags: boot

I installed dual system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. After installing anaconda, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, I reboot my computer and here is a bad error on the black screen:

```
Platform does not support this image
Failed to read header: Unsupported
Failed to load image: Unsupported
start_image() returned Unsupported
```

[image: photo of screen showing those messages]

As a result, I cannot enter Ubuntu 18.04 system. After trying to use boot repair tool, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if you've solved your issue, but i was faced with the same solved it by disabling `OS optimized Defaults` in BIOS.
my machine was Lenovo, so i followed the instructions in this link https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/ht500207-how-to-boot-from-usb-disk-in-the-bios-boot-menu-windows-8-windows-10-ideapadlenovo-laptops and it solved my problem.