# "Invalid image Failed to read header: Unsupported" - stuck in loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, lenovo

I have a Lenovo laptop with dual boot Windows 8, Ubuntu, and Kali.
Looks like there was some issue with loading Ubuntu that's currently installed (bad blocks perhaps, but I don't recall exactly), so I tried loading Ubuntu from a live USB: in Windows --> Advanced Boot Options --> restart, which gave me blue recovery screen and allowed me to choose to load Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, I clicked to load the Ubuntu that's on my harddrive (not on live USB).

Now I'm getting the below error:
[Invalid image Failed to read header: Unsupported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKyD4.jpg)

Up to this point, it seems almost same [as this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269766/bad-errors-platform-does-not-support-this-image-failed-to-read-header-unsuppor). BUT, the machine seems stuck in a loop where it's trying to load an OS that is corrupted. It won't let me get to BIOS, GRUB, or load from a live USB, or load another (working) OS.

The machine is 8 years old, and I've had dual boot Windows/Ubuntu working fine for most of this time.

What I tried (without positive results):

1. Entering BIOS via Lenovo's instructions[3](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500217-recommended-way-to-enter-bios-for-lenovo-desktops-all-in-ones-windows), and hitting Esc, F1, F2, F8, F10, etc. at startup
2. Ctrl+Alt+Del
3. restarting the machine
4. Inserting live USB with a working Linux image

Any suggestions on how to get out of this loop?